# Powershell script Stop process and proceed

Tags: powershell

I have a script where i run the shutdown.exe command on a list of computers. The script works fine until it hangs for some reason.

Is there a way that i can "ctrl + c" the shutdown command and then proceed to the next PC.

here is what im using.

```
buttonRestartWorkstations_Click={
#TODO: Place custom script here

$online = $checkedlistbox1.CheckedItems | where { Test-Connection -
ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet }

$computercount = $online.Items.Count

$progressbar1.Maximum = $online.Count
$progressbar1.Step = 1
$progressbar1.Value = 0

foreach ($computer in $online)

{
    $progressbar1.PerformStep()
    shutdown -r -t $textbox3.Text -m $computer
    Start-Sleep -s 1

}
$label2.Visible = $true
$label2.Text = "Selected Servers will reboot on the " + $textbox1.text
```

Comment: `Shutdown` is known not to work properly across the network. When we needed to do this, we ended up using WMI class `Win32_OperatingSystem`, method `Win32_ShutdownTracker()`.

Comment: Any reason you're using the old commandline `shutdown` instead of Powershell `Restart-Computer`? You'll get native error handling with it.

Comment: I couldnt find a timer for the restart-computer command

Comment: The code you posted is broken. Do not wrap code in arbitrary places to make it fit the width of the content section. Copy and paste the [mcve] you created, then select the entire code and click the `{}` symbol above the input textarea.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Restart-Computer` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-computer) would give you the ability to target multiple computers in parallel, without a problem on one computer affecting execution on others.

As you state, `Restart-Computer` is not an option for you because you want to have a *delay* before the restart is initiated on a given computer (which is what `shutdown -r -t <secs>` gives you; note that while `Restart-Computer` does have a `-Delay` parameter, its purpose is different).

*If*:

- your target computers are set up for [PowerShell remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_faq)
- *and* you can run your script *elevated* (with administrative privileges)

you can use [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) to target the computers in parallel and then *locally* run [`shutdown.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown) on them (PSv3+ syntax):

```
$delay = $textbox3.Text
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $online { 
  shutdown -r -t $using:delay
  "$(('FAILED to initiate', 'Successfully initiated')[$LASTEXITCODE -eq 0]) reboot on $env:COMPUTERNAME."
} | ForEach-Object { $progressbar1.PerformStep() }
```

Just like with your original code, execution on each target computer will return once the restart has been *initiated*, though execution will happen *in parallel*, and the responses received from the target computers are not guaranteed to be in input order.

If you wanted to *verify and wait for* successful restarts, more work would be needed.

Any errors are printed to the console in red and can later be examined in the `$Error` collection.

Note the primary purpose of `"$(('FAILED to initiate', 'Successfully initiated')[$LASTEXITCODE -eq 0]) reboot on $env:COMPUTERNAME."` is to unconditionally produce *some* (non-error) output on each computer, so that the `ForEach-Object` script block is invoked for each (`shutdown` produces no stdout output by default, and stderr output is not acted on by `ForEach-Object`).